# How to allow drag only on part of the SheetPeek of a BottomContent in BottomSheetScaffold?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

The dragging part is possible on whole rectangle (Yellow in video) and I want it to be only allowed on the Grey icon

I can drag any part of the yellow part, whether up or down, I want to allow that behavior of dragging only on the Grey part

Left Video is the same as right video, except I made the right's sheetBackgroundColor transparent

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
BottomSheetScaffold(
    topBar = { AppBar() },
    sheetElevation = ZERO_DP,
    sheetPeekHeight = BOTTOM_ICON_CONTAINER_SIZE,
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    sheetContent = {
        BottomSheetContent(modifier)
    }
) {
    HomeContent()
}


@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(0.8f)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(end = SPACING_QUADRUPLE)
                .align(Alignment.End)
                .clip(
                    RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = TRIPLE_CORNER_DP,
                        topEnd = TRIPLE_CORNER_DP
                    )
                )
                .size(BOTTOM_ICON_CONTAINER_SIZE)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
            ,


            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        )
        {
            Icon(
                modifier = modifier,
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_qr_code),
                contentDescription = stringResource(
                    id = R.string.bottom_sheet_puller
                ),
                tint = Color.Unspecified
            )
        }

        Text(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
                .padding(
                    start = SPACING_DOUBLE,
                    end = SPACING_DOUBLE,
                    bottom = SPACING_NORMAL
                ),
            text = "Scan Serial With QR",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        )
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
        )
    }
}
```

Wrong Behavior:
[image: Wrong Behavior]

Correct Intended Behavior:
[image: Intended Behavior]

- I tried replacing a rectangle composables with simple box, but bottom sheet was still considering the full width of the composable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a better solution to intercept a drag gesture and leave all of it within the green box only, but this might suffice.

I made some changes to your BottomSheetContent, intercepting a drag gesture from a `Row` weighted transparent component and leaving it empty, you can try this one, and the drag gesture is only accepted by the green box,

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(0.8f)
    ) {
        Row {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .draggable(
                        orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                        state = rememberDraggableState { 
                              Toast.makeText(context, "Non Draggable Area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        }
                    ).fillMaxWidth().height(150.dp).background(Color.Transparent)) {
            }

            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(end = 8.dp)
                    .clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 12.dp,
                            topEnd = 12.dp
                        )
                    )
                    .size(150.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
            ) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = modifier,
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = "",
                )
            }
        }


        Text(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
                .padding(
                    start = 8.dp,
                    end = 8.dp,
                    bottom = 4.dp
                ),
            text = "Scan Serial With QR",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        )
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
        )
    }
}
```

I can't show my pointer click here, but the toast shows when the left area outside of the green box is being dragged.

[image]

Comment: Amazing!

The first box in the new row overrides the behavior of the bottom sheet normal behavior, however, any UI composable after the "Draggable Icon" in the row would still be draggable, moreover, the small space next to my element is a bit short, thus it doesn't affect my intended behavior, thus I'm okay with that.

Thanks <3